# PHP explode: script working on Windows, not on Debian

Tags: php, windows, foreach, debian, explode

I have a script that does it's job perfectly on Windows but not on Debian. Both run the same PHP versions and I can't seem to figure out why it isn't working on Debian.

```
$content = file_get_contents('ua.log');
$arr = explode(PHP_EOL, $content);

foreach($arr as $x) {
    $i = explode(' ', $x);
    if($i[11] == '"user/agent1.0"'){
        $ips[] = $i[0];
    }
    else{
    };
};
```

I have checked permissions and used the long directory (/var/www/ua.log). Still doesn't seem to be working as $i returns NULL.

Comment: linux filesystem is case sensitive

Comment: Got that. Doesn't seem to be the problem, I've used the correct case.

Answer (score 1):

You might find it easier to use

```
foreach (file("/some/file.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES) as $x) {
....
}
```

Regarding the case `$i = explode(' ', $x);` - it might be also a bit different. Better to use something like `preg_split(",\s+,", $x);`, but depends on the exact file contents.

Thanks.

Comment: This actually solved the problem for some reason. I think I might submit this as bug in PHP, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Nope, it's unlikely a PHP bug. On can create files with various EOL on any platform. Merely what matters is to have a way so one doesn't have to care about those EOL. Fe things like `preg_split(",[\n\r]+,", file_get_contents(...))` could do the same job splitting the file into lines.

Comment: But, after having tested every EOL imaginable on explode, I'm not sure if that's really the problem.

Comment: Well, explode() is not dedicated to just one job. Say explode("b", "abc") will give an array with 'a' and 'c', so it's up to you which delimiter to use. Knowing an exact char(s) (like platform dependent EOL in this case) will do same job.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Kayasax's comment that Linux filesystem is **case-sensitive** (i.e. Hello.txt is not the same file as hello.txt), I have one more note to make.

On Windows, the `PHP_EOL` will default to `\r\n`, while on Linux it would be `\n` only. Therefore, if the file was created on Windows and you run your code on Linux, it could try to find Linux's end-of-line and fail to explode the file correctly and vice-versa.

Comment: I just tested it using '\n' but still returns 'NULL'. Windows does return the correct strings.

Comment: so you're sure the file is there, it's named correctly and has the correct access rights, so PHP can actually read it?

Comment: Yes. When I output the file with an echo, it works just fine.

Comment: okay then, have you tried to split the file using `"\n"` manually instead of using the `PHP_EOL` constant - and what does a `var_dump(PHP_EOL)` output?